# Research reference or source for study before selecting thesis topic

Tags: thesis, computer-science

I would like to do my master thesis on image processing. What will be best approach for study and selecting topic on this field?

Comment: A Google Scholar search, maybe? http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=image+processing

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking?  Right now, this question is terribly broad...

Comment: As currently stated, this seems like a generic question on how to select an MS thesis topic, so I have closed it as a duplicate of another question asking exactly that. If the duplicate does not address your question, please [edit] your post to clarify what you are asking and it may be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

A master's thesis assumes that you will have broad general knowledge of a subject, and detailed knowledge of a particular area of the subject.  Whether you are expected to include an experimental component or make a contribution to the body of knowledge beyond that which results from organizing material into a thesis depends on your institution.  Your advisor can help you there.  (Image processing seems like it could lend itself to any number of interesting experiments, but I speak as one who knows little about the field.)

So, you start with a relatively recent overview book and absorb that.  Consulting with your thesis advisor, pick an area of concentration.  Find a few recent papers in your area of concentration and absorb those.  Then read the papers those authors cite, and read the papers which cited the papers in your initial reading.  Using the citations, you will be "working outward from the middle" until you have a thorough grasp on your area of concentration.  Particularly, looking at papers cited by recent authors should guide you to the fundamental work in your area of concentration if you haven't found it already.

While you are becoming an expert in your area of concentration, also look for gaps in the knowledge of that area.  One of these gaps will become your thesis topic.  Work closely with your advisor so that you don't pick something that your faculty will consider trivial.  Beware also of the "solve world hunger" problem; you probably have two semesters to complete the thesis.  You cannot solve world hunger in that time.  You want to be somewhere between "order lunch" and "solve world hunger," but more in the direction of "order lunch."